# tsoutliers functionality

Tags: time-series, outliers

the tso function of the tsoutliers package locate the outliers and and shows a potential outliers you might have but i noticed that from the plot that my data might have a lot more than that, is that a statistical problem from the function or it might lack the functionality? and is tsoutliers a reliable method to detect and replace outliers ?

I also learnt about tsoutliers function which detect and suggest a replacement for the detected outliers, but when i used it on a data set, the results were 0 for all while i used tso function and it already detect an outliers , so how is that possible? do they work differently , or do i have to change some perimeters ?